# Implementing File Selection Dialog in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm interested in implementing a file selection dialog in a Rails 3 app.

I don't need to upload the file - just allow the user to select the file so I can learn its path.  I've been searching around for plugins, jquery code/plugins, etc, but haven't found anything which looks like just what I need yet.

We're using HAML, but ERB would be fine, as would jquery or other solutions.

Does any have pointers to code or plugins to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a browser security measure to hide the complete path of the uploaded file and its path will be hidden/renamed for the user's security.

However, to create an upload field using Rails' form helpers, you can try the following:

```
 <%= file_field_tag 'upload' %>
```

For some bundled processing/generators to streamline the file uploading process (if you decide to do so) you can check out [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip).